# Python import for SalesForce not Recognized

Tags: python, salesforce

I'm writing a Python script and trying to import the following to be able to access SalesForce (as specified in their documentation here: https://api.salesforceiq.com/#/python#documentation_contacts_create-a-contact)

When I do this:

```
 from relateiq.contacts import Contact
```

I get:

> ImportError: No module named relateiq.contacts

Any idea how to import correctly so I can use salesforce through Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed `relateiq.contacts`?

Comment: No...do I have to do that outside of Python?

Comment: Yes, it is an external product, not part of Python.

Comment: You might also have to beware of this:  https://www.salesforceiq.com/pricing